# Mac OS program, command adb

Tags: objective-c, macos, adb

**

I won't create programs for any command "adb"
But I have problem with Path adb.
Xcode not work with my local adb.

**

```
@implementation ViewController

NSString *adbPath = @"/Users/marchello/.nexustools";

NSString* runADBCommand(NSString *cmd)
{
    NSTask *adbDevices = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [adbDevices setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
    [adbDevices setLaunchPath:adbPath];


    adbDevices.arguments = @[cmd];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [adbDevices setStandardOutput:pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [adbDevices launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *adbComOutput;
    adbComOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return adbComOutput;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


}



-(IBAction)run:(id)sender{

    runADBCommand(@"adb devices");
}
```

If I insert adb in project.
how I set Path from project?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMuk4.png)

Comment: Have you tried passing the shell the absolute path to your command? Also, why are you running it in a shell? Why not run the tool directly in NSTask and pass the arguments as an array of arguments?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by „not work“? Do you get any error messages? Can you include errors or expected/actual output in your question? Have you tried what happens if you use another tool instead of „adb“? E.g. does a simple call to „echo“ or „yes“ work?

Comment: [General] launch path not accessible

Comment: when I press button -  NSString *adbPath = @"/Users/marchello/Desktop/installerapj/installerapj/adb";
        NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
        [task setLaunchPath:adbPath];
        [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"devices"]];
        [task launch];